# How do you make a cell value relative to another table?

Tags: mysql

in SQL assume we have a table named 'courses','student, and 'courses_taken'

courses

```
c_id key int
name text
credits int
```

student

```
s_id key int
name text
total_credits int
```

courses_taken

```
id key int
s_id foreign int
c_id foreign int
```

I would like to make the total_credits field be essentially equal to

```
select sum(c.credits) from courses c, students s, courses_taken ct where ct.c_id = courses.c_id and ct.s_id = s.s_id;
```

and I'm assuming that isnt the correct method of doing that since I've never worked with multi-table queries before, if someone could help me with that sql query as well that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost correct but missing a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause which tells the server which rows to actually sum up. Currently you are creating a temporary table where each row contains information about a single course taken, enriched by the course credits and student names. Selecting the `sum()` will just sum all the credits of all courses and all students.

Therefore you need to group by either course or student to get the sum of points for a course or student, respectively. The result for students would be:

```
select s.name, sum(c.credits) as total_credits from courses c, students s, courses_taken ct where ct.c_id = courses.c_id and ct.s_id = s.s_id GROUP BY s.s_id;
```

Comment: if I were to get rid of the total credits field, would it be possible to query the student (select * from students) and join the sum of total credits to the end of that?

Comment: select * from (
select s.s_id, s.name, sum(c.credits) from courses c, students s, courses_taken ct where ct.c_id = courses.c_id and ct.s_id = s.s_id GROUP BY s.s_id)
where s_id = 0;    would this work?

Comment: The query in my answer will list all student names and their total credits already. You could just add `AND s_id = 0` to the where clause, no subquery required.

Comment: awesome ^_^ will select s return all of the student data?

Comment: S.* would, as * would return all columns.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "built in" to MySQL that would allow you to do this directly.  You would have to write some code to update `total_credits` each time the `courses_taken` or `courses` tables are updated.

There are several options for handling this though

1. Write the code in your application to maintain the `total_credits` column.
2. Write the code in the database using triggers on the `courses` and `courses_taken` tables to keep the `total_credits` column up-to-date when rows are inserted/updated/deleted.
3. Get rid of the `total_credits` column and just calculate it when needed with a query (see @andy's answer).
4. Write a batch job that calculates `total_credits` periodically and just accept the fact that it won't always be 100% correct all the time.

Which you pick will depend on the requirements for the app you are using this database in.

Comment: Option 3 actually seems most logical, but my customer wants the total credits to be represented in a database

Comment: @Cody - I would agree.  Perhaps you could create a view using a query.  Then it would technically be "in the database" :)  I hate it when clients dictate implementation details without really understanding the technology..

Comment: I think im going to implement a 'hack' for it, read the comment made @andy, thanks for the help by the way. Much appreciated